# Find rows where a certain value ends with a specific string

Tags: sql, ingres

I need to do something like this

```
     SELECT * from table1 where name ='TEST_2014.xml'
```

But in the column 'name' the values are saved in format like `../data/flux/TEST_2014/TEST_2014.xml`

I need help to remove or edit `../data/flux/TEST_2014/` and take only `TEST_2014.xml` to do comparison on WHERE statement.

Comment: Ever heard of `like` operator?

Answer (score 6):

try

```
SELECT * from table1 where name like '%TEST_2014.xml'
```

if you have any string after '...xml' then you can use following

```
SELECT * from table1 where name like '%TEST_2014.xml%'
```

Comment: Because of folder type format (../dat/flux/TEST/TEST_2014/TEST_2014.xml); i used something like this                                                                          SELECT * from table1 where name like '%%%TEST_2014.xml%%%'

Comment: @Thulasi - modified my answer, please check it now.